# How to catch Ctrl key release?

Tags: qt, keyrelease

I press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
My first function works fine:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->modifiers()==Qt::CTRL){               //RETURNS TRUE
        ui->widget->groupmaking=true;
    } }
```

In the second, i have troubles with checking what kind of key was released. (It was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->modifiers()==Qt::CTRL){               //RETURNS FALSE. WHY?
        ui->widget->groupmaking=false;
        ui->widget->groupexist=true;
    }
}
```

So, how to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> release correctly ?

Comment: If you have found a solution, post it as an answer to your question, and eventually accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for such behavior is that there is no key modifier at the moment, when you get the key release event, because the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is already released. The right way to perform such a check would be:

```
void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Control) {
        [..]
    }
}
```